# Copy sheet using its codename and place it after a specified sheet's codename

Tags: excel, vba

Copy sheet using its codename and place it after a specified sheet's codename

Example.

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Copy After:=Sheets("Sheet5")
```

the above code works but uses the sheets display name and not the sheet's codename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This?

```
Sheet2.Copy After:=Sheet5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sheet's index instead of the stated name, like so:

```
Worksheets(2).Copy After:=Worksheets(5)
```